Virtual Environments Created via Java ProcessBuilder Cannot Install Dependencies Correctly, While PyCharm-Generated Ones Work Fine
I'm running into an issue where I create Python virtual environments using Java's ProcessBuilder on Windows, but the environments created this way(also tried from the terminal ending the same way) are unable to install the same dependencies that work fine when I create the virtual environment from PyCharm using the same base Python executable. Here's the breakdown:
I use the same Python executable (verified) for both creating environments via PyCharm and through the ProcessBuilder in my Java code.
The virtual environment created in PyCharm works perfectly, and I can install all the necessary dependencies without issues.
The virtual environment created via ProcessBuilder in my Java code, however, cannot install the same dependencies, and I get errors when trying to install them, particularly around permissions and package conflicts.
The core issue is that the virtual environment created using ProcessBuilder seems to have problems with dependency installation, even though it's based on the same Python executable as the one created in PyCharm.

The conflict is caused by:
mediapipe 0.10.0 depends on protobuf<4 and >=3.11
tensorboard 2.10.1 depends on protobuf<3.20 and >=3.9.2

These dependencies are in the venv created in pycharm and it works.
I created multiple venv in pycharm trying to make it fail so i can see where the problem is, apart from the obvious dependency issue, all of them worked.
Change the -v of protobuf and to a one that satisfies the dependency issue and then the code does not work haha.
Has anyone experienced this inconsistency when managing virtual environments via Java's ProcessBuilder/via Terminal? Could this be related to a permissions issue, or is there something specific that might be different between how PyCharm and Java handle environment creation?
private void crearYActivarAmbienteVirtual() {
    try {
        // Command to create the virtual environment
        String[] createCommand = {
                "C:\\Python310\\python.exe",
                "-m",
                "venv",
                "C:\\venv"
        };
        runProcess(
                createCommand,
                "Ambiente Virtual",
                "El ambiente virtual se ha creado correctamente.",
                "Error al crear el ambiente virtual."
        );

        // Directly invoke pip from the virtual environment
        String pipPath = "C:\\venv\\Scripts\\pip.exe"; // Adjust for Windows paths
        String[] installCommand = {
                pipPath,
                "install",
                "-r",
                "src/main/resources/PythonScript/requirements.txt"
        };

        runProcess(
                installCommand,
                "Requerimientos",
                "Los requerimientos se han instalado correctamente.",
                "Error al instalar los requerimientos."
        );
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> queueNotification("Error", "Error al configurar el ambiente virtual.", true));
    }
}

private void runProcess(String[] command, String title, String successMsg, String errorMsg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
    process.waitFor();

    if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> queueNotification(title, successMsg, false));
    } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> queueNotification("Error", errorMsg, true));
    }
}

for the errors i just do the same in the terminal and see what is throwing

ERROR: Cannot install -r src/main/resources/PythonScript/requirements.txt (line 46), -r src/main/resources/PythonScript/requirements.txt (line 78) and protobuf==3.20.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
mediapipe 0.10.0 depends on protobuf<4 and >=3.11
tensorboard 2.10.1 depends on protobuf<3.20 and >=3.9.2
Diferences in venv files
pycharm created
directory
-../user/pycharmprojects/project/venv
files

lib
share
scripts
pyvenv.cfg

command created
directory
-C/:venv
files

lib
include(empty)
scripts
pyvenv.cfg

Diference in .cfg files
pycharm
home = C:\Python310
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.10.0.final.0
virtualenv = 20.24.5
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = C:\Python310
base-exec-prefix = C:\Python310
base-executable = C:\Python310\python.exe

command
home = C:\Python310
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.0


"down vote after"? Please explain what this statement means and how it relates to your coding question and problem.

Also, where is the malfunctioning code? Also, are you checking the output of the process's error stream? If so, is it showing anything?

i used this sacred place to ask questions in the past but im so low iq that i did not even get to see a proper answer that was not  some supe high iq guy moking me before it was turned down, i promise never again, but im really out of time to get out of these so even if is a bad question or some SH-, answer and then down vote if the question deserves it

Then that is not relevant to your question, and you should get rid of it. It will only attract down-votes if you leave it in.

I have removed it for you, since such distracting meta commentary has no place within a question nor especially within its title. If you have meta type issues, then you should flag a moderator or discuss it on meta, but you really don't want to pollute your question in this way, trust me.

i really did no think the code is that important because i cannot even do it directly from the terminal, im just want to know if this happens, why it happens.
if it hellp, the java code creates the venv fine and installs the version of python needed but for some reason pycharm does something i do not know how to

If you don't know why it is happening, then you can't make such an assumption, no?

Where is the code for runProcess(...)? And again, are you handling the error stream? Are you handling all of the output streams? If not, you may have buffer overflow issues.

thanks for guide me, and please do not use complex syntax im not native, i asked in english because i thouth it would be faster (also i don't fell that bad if the mock me in another language).
but the source of the problem has to be the way the venv is creeated, i cannot thing of any other reason

@HovercraftFullOfEels would you mind removing the slew of comments asking for an edit that has already happened? You're burying the useful comments - you were right, but the problem has been resolved.

@JoseDeGracia we have to take your word for it that the exact Python executable is in fact used by both processes. However, is the working directory the same for both cases? And is the Python executable running as the same user? This may affect what rights the executable has and could result in a failed environment. Have you compared the actual resulting environments (the directories and its files) and can you tell us anything about the difference?

if there still no solution or improvement , you can try  packing all your script in  a  windows script   bat , and then  , try in terminal and java invoke , see what difference

@Grismar No they are not in the same diretory the pycharm one is on myUser/py/projects/projectxxx/venv and the other is in C/:venv.
if the  python exe is running as the same user? i would  say yes, cause im not usign 'execute as admin' and only have one user
For the files: the one create from the command has -include(emty) -lib -scripts
the pycharm one has -lib -scripts -share
the cfg file is different. ill add that to the question

You aren't reporting the stdout/stderr which might tell you of other issues. Its not clear from the question that everything is consistent with terminal launch. If you want to get same results, you'll need to run same binaries with same current directory possibly with additional environment variables that your terminal provides which are not defaulted to same for the Java launch.

@DuncG well my terminal does no provides anything because the issue with the dependencies occurs everywhere but in pycharm. i guess i just gonna put the 2gb environment directly in the java project and call it a day

simplify your script like following .
@echo off
chcp 65001

python -m venv test
call test\Scripts\activate

pip install -r requirements.txt

python xxxx.py




pip install -r requirements.txt is still the problem, i generate the requirements with the functional venv and still dependency problem

The conflict is caused by: mediapipe 0.10.0 depends on protobuf<4 and >=3.11 tensorboard 2.10.1 depends on protobuf<3.20 and >=3.9.2  this mention your encounter conflict , so just fix corresponding dependency version
